# Ads failed to load in android studio

Tags: android-studio, admob

Ad failed to load

It is always showing an error "I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3"

I can't resolve it

anyone please help me with this issue

Comment: are you trying to show real ADs without adding your device to the setTestDeviceIds() list?

Comment: when I tried to show real ADs without adding your device to the setTestDeviceIds() it shows the error. But after adding it there were no more errors. Is there any other solution for this issue?